# MongoDB : DB ceated by root user gets deleted automatically

Tags: mongodb

I added a user as below.

db.createUser(
  {
    user: "Username",
    pwd: "Password",
    roles: [  { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)

But when I create DB with this user, db gets deleted automatically and does not appear in next session.

I checked log and found out that a command runs through CMD to delete my DB.

Can someone please advise if something is wrong with the user?

Comment: I'm assuming you restarted the mongo daemon with the `--auth` option after creating the user. What do you mean by "create DB"? Do you add records to a collection? Also, can you provide relevant parts of the mongodb logs?

Comment: Thanks. But there was nothing wrong with user role or anything else. My MongoDB server got hacked.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with user role or anything else. My MongoDB server got hacked.